# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Sorry, your envelope sender is in my badmailfrom list

Tags: java, ssl, gmail, liferay, sendmail

I am getting this error while sending mail from my site. I am using liferay with SSL Configure and my gmail setup for sending mail is as follow...

```
mail.session.mail.imap.host=XXXXXXXX
mail.session.mail.pop3.host=XXXXXXXX
mail.session.mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.session.mail.smtp.host=smtpout.europe.secureserver.net
mail.session.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.session.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
mail.session.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=25
mail.session.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.session.mail.smtp.password=XXX
mail.session.mail.smtp.port=25
mail.session.mail.smtp.user=XXXXXXX
mail.session.mail.store.protocol=imap
mail.session.mail.transport.protocol=smtp

custom.organization.friendly.url.enabled=true
```

but i got the following error:

09:23:21,501 ERROR [MailEngine:489] 553 Sorry, your envelope sender is in my badmailfrom list.

09:23:21,503 ERROR [MailEngine:154] com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Sorry, your envelope sender is in my badmailfrom list.

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
at com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine._send(MailEngine.java:465)
at com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine.send(MailEngine.java:366)
at com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine.send(MailEngine.java:110)
at    com.liferay.mail.messaging.MailMessageListener.doMailMessage(MailMessageListener.java:101)
at    com.liferay.mail.messaging.MailMessageListener.doReceive(MailMessageListener.java:115)
at com.liferay.mail.messaging.MailMessageListener.receive(MailMessageListener.java:43)
at   com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.j    ava:63)
at   com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:61)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I use another ports also like  80, 3535, 25, 465 but still it gives the same error.

so, please any one have idea then please give me the proper solution.
 I appreciate him/her.

Thanks & Regards,

Bipin Vekariya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely not doing anything wrong, other than sending from a domain/email address that someone has blacklisted, cf. *553 Sorry, your* ***envelope sender*** *is in my* ***badmailfrom list.***

Does this happen no matter who you're sending to? If so, you could try relaying through another smarthost. If not, talk to the sysadm of the concrete people you can't send to. Or you could try setting another `from:` address.

In any case, do check the various email BL's (eg. using http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) to see if your origin IP is blacklisted.

Cheers,